# Trying to solving a nonlinear second order ODE using power series method

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

The equation of a pendulum with damping is given by 
$$ y'' + \mu y' +K\sin(y) = 0$$
find the series solution.

Now if it were given assume $y \rightarrow 0$ then the question becomes quite simple, but since it isn't given so I was inclined on using the series expansion of $\sin(y)$, but that would make it extremely complicated.

Can I assume that $\sin(y)$ can be approximated by $y~$? Deeply appreciate any help. Thank you.